# Getting Column Names from SQL Alchemy result when not using Declarative Syntax

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I query my db through SQL Alchemy like so:

```
dev_engine = create_engine('mysql://...')

get_prod_instrument = "select * from market_instrument inner join exchange_instrument on market_instrument.id = exchange_instrument.instrument_id \
inner join tick_size on market_instrument.id = tick_size.instrument_id \
left join futures on market_instrument.id = futures.instrument_id \
inner join (select distinct(substring(m.symbol, 1, 2)) as product from market_instrument as m inner join fills as f on m.id=f.instrument_id where symbol<>\"\" and fill_timestamp between CURDATE() - INTERVAL " + str(last_days) + \
                         " DAY AND NOW()) r on market_instrument.symbol like concat(r.product, '%') \
where symbol not like '%_old%' and symbol not like '%:%';"

result = dev_engine.execute(get_prod_instrument)
```

`result` is a large table. I want to be able to the column names of this table in sqlalchemy. Is there a way to adjust my query or to use Python to get the column names in some python object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the column names like so:

```
dev_engine = create_engine('mysql://...')

get_prod_instrument = "select * from market_instrument inner join exchange_instrument on market_instrument.id = exchange_instrument.instrument_id \
inner join tick_size on market_instrument.id = tick_size.instrument_id \
left join futures on market_instrument.id = futures.instrument_id \
inner join (select distinct(substring(m.symbol, 1, 2)) as product from market_instrument as m inner join fills as f on m.id=f.instrument_id where symbol<>\"\" and fill_timestamp between CURDATE() - INTERVAL " + str(last_days) + \
                         " DAY AND NOW()) r on market_instrument.symbol like concat(r.product, '%') \
where symbol not like '%_old%' and symbol not like '%:%';"

result = dev_engine.execute(get_prod_instrument)
# getting columns
description_tuple = result.cursor.description
headers = [k[0] for k in description_tuple] # a list of the column names
```

`result.cursor.description` is a tuple of tuples, and each tuple has as its very first attribute the column name

I don't think this is the best solution because this is a direct access of one of the underlying objects of the ResultProxy object rather than retrieving the object through a getter, but I couldn't find any encapsulation methods to retrieve the column names when not using declarative syntax.